# DJANGO render to PDF , QUERYSET

Tags: django, pdf, render

i am working on my django-admin, and i am trying to render to pdf my obj. This is my def:

```html
def Imprimir(self, request, obj):

    data = {
            'id':obj.values_list('id', flat=True),
            'freguesia': obj.values_list('freguesia',flat=True), 
            'rua': obj.values_list('rua',flat=True),
            'porta': obj.values_list('porta',flat=True),
            'tavaria':obj.values_list('tipo_avaria',flat=True),
    }
    pdf = render_to_pdf('daa/imprimir/avarias_pdf.html', data)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22V1I.png

The problem is only show my queryset and the ID, i want to show the name of the queryset not the id. anyone can help me?

**My avarias_pdf.html**

```html
<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID:</th>
                    <th>Freguesia:</th>
                    <th>Rua:</th>  
                    <th>Porta:</th>
                    <th>Tipo avaria:</th>
                 </tr>
                  <tr> 
                        <td>{{id}}</td>   
                        <td>{{freguesia}}</td>
                        <td>{{rua}}</td> 
                        <td>{{porta}} </td>
                        <td>{{tavaria}}</td>
                    </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: You need to show your avarias_pdf template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the right way to do this at all. You should remove all those `values_list` calls, and iterate through the queryset in the template.

```
def Imprimir(self, request, obj):
    data = {'obj': obj}
    pdf = render_to_pdf('daa/imprimir/avarias_pdf.html', data)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

...

```
{% for item in obj %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>   
        <td>{{ item.freguesia }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.rua }}</td> 
        <td>{{ item.porta }} </td>
        <td>{{ item.tavaria }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: and if i have a ForeignKey to id, and wanted to print the name of another field in another model , how do i do?